# Is the maximum spin-frecuency of a neutron star related with the stiffness of an equation of state?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, astrophysics, neutron-stars

I know that stiffer EoS gives bigger stars and stars with bigger maximum masses. The problem is that I'm computing the maximum spin-frecueny of a neutron star for two EoS, and I'm getting higher $\Omega_{max}$ for the softer one. For me this is counterintuitive. Is this true?